# How To Create an ASP.NET Application from Multiple Projects

Tags: asp.net, webforms

i have just went through this article to create a web application with multiple web application.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/307467/how-to-create-an-asp-net-application-from-multiple-projects-for-team-d
my requirement exactly match this.i have a large web application which i have to deliver in multiple phases and when deploying the changes of any child project,it should not affect the existing running child project or main project.i should be able to use the use control or dll between the child projects.

i need a sample of this approach. i have tried to create the same but the sharing of user control etc. between the child projects is not working.i think ,i am doing something wrong. if anyone have a sample or example of this approach then please share.
  i am working on asp.net web form application not MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you are using source control effectively, this should not present any problems. You can add a child project at any time and keep it checked out to yourself. When you are satisfied with unit testing you can perform integration testing before putting it live.

The only issue I see with your description of the problem lies with attempting to share User Controls between projects. People have been experiencing problems with this approach for a long time, especially with the Web Site Template. It apparently is possible for Web Forms projects:

[How do I share user controls between web applications in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710076/how-do-i-share-user-controls-between-web-applications-in-asp-net)

[Creating and Using User Control Libraries](http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/UserControls/UserControls.aspx)

Personally, I think it depends on what you are trying to to with the User Controls. For example, are they just displaying something that is repeated on different pages? In that scenario, make more judicious use of Master Pages. If they are being used for functionality, then consider the creation of a library of Custom Server Controls and reference these in your projects?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. will check the same.